# I can run my app but cannot debug it via android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

In my test project, I can run my application but cannot debug it, when I run my app the `apply changes and restart activity` button and `apply code changes` are disabled and `report app` not detected.

And in the application window it shows a dialog with below message

`application .... is waiting for the debugger to attach.`

I tried following:

- select app to be debugged
- `android:debuggable="true"` in manifest
- In build

  ```
  debug
  {
      debuggable true
  }
  ```
- tried adb kill server and restart it

[Issue snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBFXb.png)

Comment: Do you set your build variant to Debug ?

Comment: yes i do that .

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use

```
Attach Debugger to Android Process
```

Comment: Also, if you are using a physical device check that it has USB debugging enabled and authorized

Comment: i can not attach debugger when i wanna to choose process the "ok" button is deactive

Comment: First you have to run the app then you can Attach debugger.

Comment: i run app right now but cannot attach debugger

Comment: when process dialog popup you need to select your app's process, then "Ok" button will be activated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.

### Solution

Using a laptop, make sure the USB connection is going straight from the device to the computer.

I had a multi-USB port that appears to have been preventing the debugger from attaching to the process.  There may be ports and adapters rated to handle this type of process, but mine is not.